# What is the PHP equivalent of Java System.out.println

Tags: java, php, console

What is the equivalent print syntax this Java code in PHP?

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
System.out.println("Lorem Ipsum");
```

I can achieve this in PHP by using "\n" in the end of the string

```
print "Hello World\n";
print "Lorem Ipsum";
```

But I don't want to use "\n" every time I want to print something on console

Comment: Then write a function `println` for it that prints the argument plus a newline

Comment: ^-- This. And prefer using `PHP_EOL` rather than `'\n'`

Comment: So there is no built-in syntax to achieve this?

Comment: `I don't want to use "\n" every time`...so then just write a function which does it for you. And then use that instead of print or echo directly. This sort of situation is a good illustration of the whole point of re-usable functions. There's no built-in thing no, but it's trivial to create your own. And yeah, use PHP_EOL instead of \n so that it's platform-independent.

Comment: @NMNaufaldo no, there isn't. And if you take a look at [how java does it](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/cf44386c8fe3/src/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#l774), you should be fine with just writing a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure that you've worked it out by now that you need a function to do this (from the very useful comments). But in case others are looking for something quick and **simple**:

```
<?php

function println(string $string = '')
{
    print($string . PHP_EOL);
}
```

Make your own improvements if needed, but this should work.